# Is this possible to charge clients credit card after one day of placing an order through paypal?

Tags: paypal

One of my client wants an option to charge client's credit card after one day of placing an order so I am wondering if this is feasible to do with Paypal.

Comment: show your code.  we can help you even better that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Authorize the transaction, and then delay-capture the funds. This method us usually used with delayed fulfillment transactions, such as drop-ship, or build to order transactions. See [Using Authorization & Capture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/) for more information.